# htaccess - remove index.php and keep a variable without key

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

original url is one of the following:

- `example.com`
- `example.com/index.php`
- `example.com/index.php?c=lorem`

if `example.com` - nothing should be done
if `example.com/index.php` - it should be visible as `example.com` and here is my code - works fine:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

if `example.com/index.php?c=lorem` it should be visible as `example.com/lorem`

and `lorem` should be accessible by php in both cases:

- if a user type `example.com/index.php?c=lorem` or
- a user type `example.com/lorem`

pls help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?c=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples.
Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##This rule is for handling index.php file in uri.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R=301,NC,L]
   
##This rule is to redirect from index.php?c=lorem to lorem in uri.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php\?c=(lorem)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

##Rule for non-existing files/directories to index.php with variables.
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

---

---

***OR:*** Above is for specifically `lorem` in case your query string could be anything then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##This rule is for handling index.php file in uri.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R=301,NC,L]
   
##This rule is to redirect from index.php?c=lorem to lorem in uri.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php\?c=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

##Rule for non-existing files/directories to index.php with variables.
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your code also works. I accepted Anubhava's only because he was the first - in the absence of the other right criteria. I hope that's okay