# Remove ?q= from url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want this:

```
https://example.com/something
```

From this:

```
https://example.com/?q=something
```

I found many similar questions stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me, so please help me.

For example i tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index\.php?q=$1
```

with this php code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $_GET['q'] ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it's always shows "index.php"

Comment: If none of the existing questions provide a solution (while they should, since this is a very common thing to do), please ask a question describing in detail what you have tried and what problems you are facing.

Comment: @MarkusAO for example i tried this:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index\.php?q=$1`
but it always returns "index.php"

Comment: Please update your question with the details of what you have tried.

Comment: It sounds like you have a different rewrite somewhere else, which is running _before_ this one, so that the URL is being rewritten twice: `/something` -> `/index.php`, and then `/index.php` -> `/index.php?q=index.php` To test that theory, try making a page called something else, like `test.php`, and changing your rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*) test\.php?q=$1`

Comment: You could also try enabling logging for the rewrite module, and posting the results of that in your question. [Instructions for Apache 2.4 are here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), or if those don't work try [the version for 2.2 here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

Comment: The rule you posted will _roughtly_ do the opposite of what you ask.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66942536/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/7677070/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*) index\.php?q=$1
> ```
>
> ...but it's always shows "index.php"

That's because the rather generic pattern `^(.*)` also matches `index.php` and ends up rewriting the request to `index.php?q=index.php` on the second pass of the rewrite engine (when used in a *directory* context, like `.htaccess`).

If your URL's (like `/something`) don't contain dots then you could simply exclude dots from the regex, so it won't match `index.php`. Excluding dots also means it should avoid matching any static resources (that usually map directly to files that end in a file extension, which are naturally delimited by a dot, eg. `image.jpg`, `styles.css`, etc.).

For example, try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

There's no need to backslash-escape the literal dot in the *substitution* string (2nd argument) since this is a "regular" string, not a regex, and the dot carries no special meaning here.

Comment: thank you it worked!